# How to convert json to csv in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a nested json file to convert it to csv .Below is the json format ,

```
[{'year': '2020' }, 
('data', [{'location': {'coordinates': {'lat': 22.0, 'lon': -33.0}}, 
'times': {'date': '2020-08-30', 'time': '12:00'}, 
'values': {'surface': 45, 'wave': 6.8, 'temp': 283, 'height': 1.8}},
{'location': {'coordinates': {'lat': 22, 'lon': -33}},
'times': {'date': '2020-08-30', 'time': '13:00'}, 
'values': {'surface': 42, 'wave': 6.7, 'temp': 283.1, 'height': 2.88}})]
```

These json format to be converted into csv :

output required is as follows:

```
lat  lon  date       time   surface  wave  temp  height
22   -33  2020-08-30 12:00   45      6.8   283    1.8
22   -33  2020-08-30 13.00   42      6.7   283.1  2.88
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: json you posted is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage to change your nested JSON to something like this:

```
{
        "year": 2020,
        "data": {
            "location": {
                "coordinates": {
                    "lat": 22.0,
                    "lon": -33.0
                }
            },
            "times": { 
                "date": "2020-08-30",
                "time": "12:00"
             },
            "values": { 
                "surface": "2020-08-30",
                "wave": "12:00",
                "temp": 283,
                "height": 1.8
             }
        }
    },
    ...
```

You can use this code to convert to `csv`:

```
import csv
import json

x = """[
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "data": {
            "location": {
                "coordinates": {
                    "lat": 22.0,
                    "lon": -33.0
                }
            },
            "times": { 
                "date": "2020-08-30",
                "time": "12:00"
             },
            "values": { 
                "surface": "2020-08-30",
                "wave": "12:00",
                "temp": 283,
                "height": 1.8
             }
        }
    },
   
]"""

x = json.loads(x)

f = csv.writer(open("Example.csv", "wb+"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["year", "data", "location", "times", "values"])

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["year"],
                x["data"],
                x["location"]["coordinates"]["lat"],
                x["location"]["coordinates"]["lon"],
                x["times"]["date"],
                x["times"]["time"],
                x["values"]["surface"],
                x["values"]["wave"],
                x["values"]["temp"],
                x["values"]["height"]])
```

Comment: `for x in x` what is this?

Comment: It's a different way of writing a longer for loop